# WCF with custom binding and authentication - does access over https offers security benefits?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I created a service that uses custom binding and is secured with username / pass using ASP.NET membership. It needed a certificate, which I understand is used to encrypt the authentication info.

Does it also encrypt the whole message? Does it means the message is already secured (encrypted)? Do I get any security benefit if I access the service over SSL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF has (2) types of security - Transport Level (SSL) and Message Level (certificates, keys). If the message is not secured, any software running on the WCF host/client machine that receives the message can interpret its value. However, message security provides added protection to ensure that other apps running on your server cannot compromise the contents. The downside is performance overhead of encrypting the message contents and distribution of keys/certs. It truly depends on the needs and level of protection surrounding the applications.

If your application is internal - you likely don't need to use message protection. There are many factors to consider though.

Comment: The application is not used internally. It will allow client applications, distributed over internet and (possible) implemented using different technologies to upload some specific data to the application service, and the retrieve and process that data.

Comment: The service interface (OperationContracts) does contains only params for actual data, and the user the data belongs to is actually identified through the membership User object representing actual logged user.  Any drawback at this approach?

Comment: So if I only use message level security (username / pass and server side certificate used by WCF), is the full message encrypted?

Comment: Yes - Message Level encrypts the entire message. Check this MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx for more details on pros/cons of message security.